# Fetching URLs with JS from file?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Simple question from a noob :). The line below is from a javascript im trying to understand. The script is fetching data from a csv file to build a table based on a price slider. This line is the url that makes the visitor go to a specific website (a button i a table cell). My question is: What kind of file is in the /links/ directory and what exactly does '+line[6]+' mean?

```
content+='<td><a href="http://www.exampel.com/links/'+line[6]+'"
```

In a browser, the url looks like this (example): http://www.exampel.com/links/comapanyA

Comment: Better ad that to the question. And to answer, it's string concatenation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without the actual file, I don't think it is discernible what exact type of file it is.

But, I can answer the "what exactly does '+line[6]+' mean?":

The plus signs on either side are string concatenation. So you are adding the results of "line[6]" to the url string.

"line[6]" is an array, with the sixth element being called by the index number "6".

Comment: Glad it helped. If you can accept my answer, that would be appreciated.